# Impossible to cast void in List C#

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to make a parser which will read a CSV file and add information in a List.

My problem is that when I make my loop to add in a Dictionary, the header(key) and the value(value), I have a error

> "Impossible to cast void in List" (translated from French).

Code:

```
private List<string> header = null;
private List<string> tableauValeurs = null;

public bool ParseCSVFile(string csvPath)
{
   bool result = false;

   if (File.Exists(csvPath))
   {
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvPath))
      {
          var firsLine = sr.ReadLine();

          this.header = firsLine.Split(';').ToList();

          while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
          {
             var line = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');

             this.tableauValeurs = new List<string>();
             Dictionary<string, List<string>> lineDico = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

             for (int i = 0; i < this.header.Count; i++)
             {
                 lineDico.Add(this.header[i], ***this.tableauValeurs.Add(line[i]***);
             }
         }
         result = true;
      }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) `Add` is a void method. It doesn't return a new list.
So, add your element into the list first, then put the list into the `Dictionary`.

```
this.tableauValeurs.Add(line[i]);
lineDico.Add(this.header[i], this.tableauValeurs);
```

Comment: Resolved, thanks!! any way to put my subject resolved?

Comment: just mark (cocher le sign en vert dans ma réponse) my answer . It's all

Answer (score 1):

Add returns void. You need to add your line to tableauValeurs first and then add tableauValeurs to your Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
lineDico.Add(this.header[i], this.tableauValeurs.Add(line[i]));
```

Now; `lineDico` is `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, so the `Add` method wants a `string` and a `List<string>`; `this.header[i]` looks fine, but `this.tableauValeurs.Add(line[i])` will return `void`, which isn't a `List<string>`. So: what is the `List<string>` that you intended to add as the value in `lineDico`?

Comment: Was the values of CSV file that i was trying to put in my list nut its resolved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`this.tableauValeurs.Add(line[i])` doesnt return a list.

Probably best to use: (no need of this if field is only in this class)

```
tableauValeurs.Add(line[i]));
lineDico.Add(header[i], tableauValeurs);
```

If you wish to have a new list associated with dictionary, move the new list declaration after for loop.